# how to access responsedata in javascript array contains object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In javascript array, contains value (ie; type is object). that object contains another array of values. Inside this Array had 3 objects. And the object  there are some variables. how to push one variable to another array in javascript

```
var studentData = new Array();

success: function(responseData) {
    $.each(responseData, function(index, item) { 
        studentData.push(responseData.markMasterList(0).markMasterDetails(i).student.name);
```

responseData shows ..

```
Array[5]
>0: Object 
   >markArray: Array[1]
      >0: Object
        >markDetailsArray: Array[10]
           >0: Object
               >student: Object
                  >name  //How to push this variable to studentData
           >1: Object
           >2: Object
           >3: Object
>1: Object
```

I tried with this one but got error on console

```
studentData.push(responseData.markMasterList(0).markMasterDetails(i).student.name);
```

error shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more snippets, I can only gues, but You might have missed the array syntax.

You need **[ ]** to refer to an array ( /object ) key, not **( )**

```
studentData.push(responseData.markMasterList[0].markMasterDetails[i].student.name);
```

( I know, your question was referring to objects, but in JS, arrays and objects have a lot in common. F.e: )

```
var a = { 1 : "a" , 2 : "b" };
a[ 1 ] // Gives "a"
```